# jquery- avoid double clicks

Tags: jquery, events, click, jquery-animate

I have a simple animation the problem is I want the animation to end before I can click again?

```
$(".next").click(function() {

 $('#result').animate({
    left: '-=250',
   }, 1000, function() {
  pos = $('#result').position();

  if (pos.left <= -550) {
$('.next').hide();
  }
  if (pos.left <= -250) {
    $('.prev').show();
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you have a fiddle you can share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple, use the `.data()` method to set a clickable flag on the item. You can re-enable it in your complete function.

From jQuery.com: [.data() Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

> The .data() method allows us to attach data of any type to DOM elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore from memory leaks.
>
> We can set several distinct values for a single element and retrieve them later:

Using the **complete** method on your animation (Which you're already using to show/hide your next / previous buttons, we can re-enable the button to be clicked.

Note that we store `$(this)` into `btn` so it can be accessed from the closure of the **complete** function.

```
$(".next").click(function() {
  var btn = $(this);
  if (btn.data('running'))
    return;

  btn.data('running', true);

  $('#result').animate({
    left: '-=250',
    }, 1000, function() {
       pos = $('#result').position();

       if (pos.left <= -550) {
         $('.next').hide();
       }
       if (pos.left <= -250) {
         $('.prev').show();
       }

       // Unset it here, this lets the button be clickable again
       btn.data('running', false);
    }
   );
});
```

Comment: `.data` is not the same as `data-item="asd"` attributes. It's been around since jQuery 1.3 and stores data referenced to the jQuery object that wraps that dom. As of jQuery 1.4.3 the .data() gets auto-populated by `data-attributes` but `.data()` is fully supported in pre HTML5. It is just storing a javascript object in memory really.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it so that the animation automatically finished before the `animate` starts again:

```
$('#result').stop(true, true).animate({ ...
```

Answer (score 1):

disable the button on click and use the complete function call of the .animate function to re-enable it:

.animate( properties [, duration] [, easing] **[, complete]** )

**complete** A function to call once the animation is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the button on click, and use use the "SetTimeout" function to enable it after the same period of time.

```
$(".next").click(function() {

   $(this).enabled = false;
   setTimeout('enableButtons()', 250);     }

   $('#result').animate({
      left: '-=250',
   }, 1000, function() {
    pos = $('#result').position();

  if (pos.left <= -550) {
$('.next').hide();
  }
  if (pos.left <= -250) {
    $('.prev').show();
  }
});

function enableButtons() {
    $(".next").enabled = true;
}
```